# Reverse geolocate using lat/lon to get street address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I created a function making use of Googles Geocoder API to perform a reverse geolocation. It pulls lat/lon from the browser's native functions and sends them through to Google. The intent of the function is to get the approximate street address of the user (ie. `123 Fake Street`). The City/Municipality, Province/State, Country and Post code are not wanted, just the street address.

```
function geoSuccess(pos) {
    Geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    Geocoder.geocode({location: {lat:pos.coords.latitude,lng:pos.coords.longitude}}, function(r, s) {
        if (s === 'OK') {
            var found = false,
                    x = 0;
            do {
                if (r[x].address_components[0].types.indexOf('route') !== -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
                x++;
            } while(!found && x < r.length);
            alert(r[x-1].address_components[0].long_name);
        }
    });
}
```

Based on how the function works, it scans through the resulting JSON to find the route. However, there is a discrepancy for mobile devices where the accuracy is different than desktops. Despite searching for `route`, frequently mobile devices will return either the wrong data (closest highway).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: If you are looking for a building's street address, you probably don't want type "route" [route indicates a named route (such as "US 101")], you probably want [street_address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes) (or maybe premise)

Comment: For the purposes of the code, street_address returned too much data, so route was used instead.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the comments made (and revising the question), the function was rewritten. Nested loops through the JSON were made to tally up all of the unique data from the query. From their, street address was manually recreated instead of relying on Google to provide the desired result.

```
function geoSuccess(pos) {
    var Geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    Geocoder.geocode({location: {lat:pos.coords.latitude,lng:pos.coords.longitude}}, function(r, s) {
        if (s === 'OK') {
            var addr = [];
            r.each(function(o) {
                o.address_components.each(function(a) {
                    addr[a.types.join('.')] = a.long_name
                });
            });

            alert(addr['street_number']+' '+addr['route']);
        }
    });
}
```

So far this stands as the best way I found to get the data I wanted.